# Externalize hibernate.cfg.xml from war maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, batch-file, maven-assembly-plugin

I'am packing my java web application to a zip file containing all dependencies and other things .. using maven assembly plugin, and i wrote a batch script so as to deploy the war and run it without openning eclipse ...

the problem here is that i want to run this batch file for others Databases in other computers, here i need your help to tell me if there is a way to externalize the hibernate.cfg.xml to directly configure the databases to whom my application will be linked to.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have found that I must specify the connection properties (Username, password, connection.url, dialect ...) in the `hibernate.properties`.
And the class mapping must remain in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. 
And by placing them both at the `resources`, Hibernate will locate them both and extract what he needs :D

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure `property` file for externalize the `hibernate.cfg.xml`. create `hibernate.properties` into class path and set variable and value for configuration of hibernate. you can refer bellow sample code for it:

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <map>
            <entry key="connection.driver_class" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" />
            <entry key="connection.username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
            <entry key="connection.password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
            <entry key="transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory" />
        </map>
    <property>
 </bean>
```

hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
hibernate.connection.username = root
hibernate.connection.password = root
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without including spring ? or it is mandatory ?

Comment: no no.. it is not mandatory to use  this. and for proper configuration you can refer this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173127/externalize-hibernate-cfg-xml-from-war-maven/45173364?noredirect=1#comment77316235_45173364, in this link you can get konw about configuration. ans use this configuration into property file.